# MySQL query with multiple AND operators not working

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with a query:

```sql
SELECT l.LookupID, l.companyID, c.companyID, c.companyname, l.selectionID 
FROM companies c 
INNER JOIN lookup l 
ON c.companyID = l.companyID AND c.companyID = 1 AND c.companyID = 2
WHERE l.selectionID = 2 AND l.selectionID = 2
GROUP BY l.LookupID
```

Obviously the `AND` doesn't return the result expected. The result I'm expecting is that both `selectionID` 2 and 4 must exist in `companyID` 1 and 2.

I was thinking about using `Count(*)` but I'm very confused.

Comment: `WHERE l.selectionID = 2 AND l.selectionID = 2` will not fail but is duplicated. What did you mean?

Comment: So you want both the companies 1 and 2 to be returned where they both contain selectionIds 2 and 4?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my poor question format

Comment: @MemoryPointer Please give table definitions and expected results

Comment: Maybe you wanted an `in()` expression? btw I don't see a `4` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are absolutely zero rows in `c` where this condition will be TRUE. (If one of these conditions is true, the other is guaranteed to be false.)

```
 c.companyID = 1 AND c.companyID = 2
```

---

Without a sample of example data and an expected result, the specification is not clear. There are several interpretations. and those interpretations can differ in significant ways. So that means any answer to the question is just a "guess".

Here's an example of returning rows from `company` where there are matching rows in `lookup` for both `selectionID` 2 and 4.

```
 SELECT c.companyID
      , c.companyname
   FROM companies c
   JOIN ( SELECT l.companyID 
            FROM lookup l
           WHERE l.companyID IN (1,2)
             AND l.selectionID IN (2,4)
           GROUP BY l.companyID
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.selectionID) = 2
        ) d
     ON d.companyID = c.companyID
  ORDER BY c.companyID
```

That's just an example of how we might return a particular result. Again, without a more definitive specification (example data, expected output), we're just guessing.

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. e.g.

```
 SELECT c.companyID
      , c.companyname
   FROM companies c
  WHERE c.companyID in (1,2)
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM lookup l2 
                  WHERE l2.companyID   = c.companyID
                    AND l2.selectionID = 2
               )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM lookup l4 
                  WHERE l4.companyID   = c.companyID
                    AND l4.selectionID = 4
               )
  ORDER BY c.companyID
```